# How to get the Ace mod self-interaction key to work?

Tags: arma-2

I'v downloaded the Ace mod for ARMA 2 OA. It says that the self-interaction key is the right Windows key. However, when I press it, nothing happens. I've tried changing it but it still does nothing. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Somtimes the right and left Windows keys get reversed because of a issue in the client.